# Proof that $\log^2 n = O(n)$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, asymptotics, solution-verification

I would like to prove that $\log^2(n) = O(n)$.

My attempt so far is:

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log^2(n) = \infty \text{ and } \lim_{n \to \infty} n = \infty$ we get from L'Hôpital's rule that (let $f(n) = \log^2n$ and $g(n) = n$)

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{\prime}(n)}{g^{\prime}(n)}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{\prime}(n)}{1} = \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\log n} \cdot \frac{\ln 2}{2} = \infty$$

Hence $\log^2 n = O(n)$

Is this valid, and if not, where is it breaking?

EDIT:
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{\prime}(n)}{g^{\prime}(n)}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{\prime}(n)}{1} = \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2log n}{n}  = 0$$

Comment: $f'(n)$ is not correct. Check the derivative again.$f'=\dfrac  {2 \log n }{n}$

Comment: Ah thanks @Aryadeva. I don't know how i flipped that around.

Comment: you're welcome ......

Comment: @sn3jd3r I'm not sure you know what $O(n)$ means. It does not mean they have the same limit-- else $\ln(n)=O(n^3)$! Informally, it means that the dominating term is "roughly" $n$, for example $3n$ or $50n+\ln(n)$. Would you mind editing your question to clarify what you mean?

Comment: @DUO What? indeed ln(n) = O(n^3). This is standard. It does not mean that the dominating term is "roughly" $n$ in any definition i am aware of. Rather it means  if there exists a positive real number $M$ and a real number $x_0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M g(x) \quad$ for all $x \geq x_{0}$ then $f(x) = O(g(x))$

Comment: @sn3jd3r Ah, I think I know understand what you mean. Yes, indeed, $\ln^2(n)=O(n)$ because $\ln^2(n)$ is, informally, $\leq n$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log^2 x}{x}\stackrel{H.R.}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2\log x}{x}\stackrel{H.R.}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{x}=0$$

therefore $\log^2 n = O(n)$ and $\log^2 n = o(n)$.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your last line. If it is $o(n)$, then it is also $O(n)$, isn't it?

Comment: There may be a typo in your response, as $f = o(g) \implies f = O(g)$. Moreover, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) / g(n) < \infty \implies f = O(g)$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes sorry, now it is  fixed!

Comment: @AlexandruDinu Thanks fixed!

Answer (score 1):

In light of the actual limit it is better (i.e. more accurate) to use asymptotic relations other than $O(\cdot)$. Since the limit, as @user showed, is $0$, the relationship is in fact
$$
f(n) = o(g(n))\\
g(n) = \omega(f(n))
$$
Here $f(n) = \log^2 n$ and $g(n) = n, \ \omega(f(n))$ means that the ratio diverges (tends to infinity), $o(\cdot)$, as explained above, means that the ratio converges to $0$